How to line break text beneath underbrace in amsmath?
How can I line break text under an underbrace so that there won't be any spacing issues?
amsmath probably isn't necessary for this, but it makes the problem more clear because of \underbrace.
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\begin{document}
\[(equation\ 2)(\underbrace{equation\ 2}_{\text{I want to line break this text.}})\]
\end{document}



You could use the \substack macro, which is also provided by the amsmath package.

Note that the \substack material protrudes on both sides of the base material ("equation 2"). If there's material on the base line on either side of "equation 2" which needs to be placed snugly against this string, I suggest you load the mathtools package (a superset of the amsmath package) and encase the \substack{...} material in a \mathclap{...} wrapper.
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath} % for '\underbrace' and '\substack' macros
\begin{document}
\[
\underbrace{\text{equation 2}}_{%
      \substack{\text{I want to line}\\ 
                \text{break this text.}}}
\]
\end{document}


Addendum to elaborate on @DonHosek's comment, in which he noted the tiny amount of vertical space between the lines "I want to line" and "break this text". For the case at hand, the narrowness is due to the upper line not containing any letters (such as j, p, q, or y) that have material below the baseline. While inserting \strut directives in one or both lines will certainly succeed in increasing the space between the two lines, doing so would actually be too much of a good thing. For a good fix, it suffices to insert \vphantom{y} at the end of the first line, i.e., change
      \substack{\text{I want to line}\\

in the code shown above to
      \substack{\text{I want to line}\vphantom{y}\\

Of course, \vphantom{y} is a typographical strut as well -- just a lot smaller overall than \strut.


I would suggest adding \strut to each line to improve the vertical spacing in the \substack.

Thank you Mico, I appreciate your insights. By the way, @DonHosek, is there a way to automate the strut height decision, or is it just by eye?

@DonHosek - Thanks. I wouldn't insert \strut on the first line as its distance to the underbrace looks alright to me. I might insert \textstyle\mathstrut right after \text{break this text} in order to increase the separation between the two lines of text. I'll post an addendum to flesh out this idea.

@Jasper - I'd say this should be adjusted by eye. I think the problem arose because there are no letters with material below the baseline (such as j, p, q, and y) in the upper line. If the upper line contained even one such letter, the line spacing problem would be neglible.

An idea would be to use tabular, but this needs some help, because \text only sets the font size and not the baseline skip.
On the other hand, the full set of features of \text isn't needed, because such constructions will only be used in display math.
I provide \ubracetext and \obracetext that will do; if * follows, the text will be typeset in a zero width box (à la \mathclap). The inner tabular uses a baseline skip that's 10% more than the font size; it is top aligned for \ubracetext and bottom aligned for \obracetext. A single line is not a problem.
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}

% use these two, rather than \underbrace and \overbrace
\NewDocumentCommand{\ubrace}{mm}{{\underbrace{#1}_{#2}}}
\NewDocumentCommand{\obrace}{mm}{{\overbrace{#1}^{#2}}}

\makeatletter
\NewDocumentCommand{\ubracetext}{smm}{% *-version uses zero width
  \ubrace{#2}{% now the subscript using tabular
    \uo@brace{#1}{t}{#3}%
  }%
}
\NewDocumentCommand{\obracetext}{smm}{% *-version uses zero width
  \obrace{#2}{% now the subscript using tabular
    \uo@brace{#1}{b}{#3}%
  }%
}
\newcommand{\uo@brace}[3]{%
  \makebox[\IfBooleanTF{#1}{0pt}{\width}]{% zero width if *-version
    \linespread{1}% just in case
    \fontsize{\sf@size}{\fpeval{1.1*\sf@size}}\selectfont
    \begin{tabular}[#2]{@{}c@{}}#3\end{tabular}%
  }%
}
\makeatother

\begin{document}

\begin{gather}
(equation\ 1)(\ubracetext{equation\ 2}{I want to line \\ break this text})
\\
(equation\ 1)(\ubracetext*{equation\ 2}{I want to line \\ break this text})
\end{gather}

\bigskip
\hrule
\bigskip

\begin{gather}
(equation\ 1)(\obracetext{equation\ 2}{I want to line \\ break this text})
\\
(equation\ 1)(\obracetext*{equation\ 2}{I want to line \\ break this text})
\end{gather}

\end{document}


Why do I recommend not using \underbrace and \overbrace? Because they've weird syntax and have a peculiar behavior with respect to spacing around them.

+1 for simplifying the (implicit) use of \mathclap. :-)
